# Button "post on facebook" android : check permission on click

Tags: android, facebook

I have a facebook connect feature in my app, it stores fb id and other information in SharedPreferences.

I check permission when user clicks on "post on facebook", to eventually display scope if needed then toggle the button.

But when I kill app and restart, the session is null and I have to make user login again.

It's bad UX because he is already connected since my app has it's fb info.

```
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            if(session == null){
                session = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(getApplicationContext());
            }
            if(session!=null && session.isOpened()){
                for(String permission : session.getPermissions()){
                    Log.e("perm", permission);
                }
                if(session.getPermissions().containsAll(PERMISSIONS)){
                    switchFb();
                }else {
                    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(FlashActivity.this, PERMISSIONS));
                }


            }else{
                Log.d("session", "null");
            }

        }
```

Comment: The SDK will cache the credentials, and shouldn't force the user to re-login. Are you closing the session anywhere?

Comment: No. Happens only for users who didn't installed Facebook.. It's too few to spend much time on it. Thanks all

Comment: Hmm, even if they don't have the FB app installed, the credentials should still be cached. The only time the SDK clears the cache is if the user explicitly clicks on Logout (if you use the LoginButton provided by the SDK), or if you call session.closeAndClearTokenInformation().